# How to create a regEx to extract value from a string with square brackets in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string **"Something[Anything]"**. 
First I want to check whether string contains Square brackets if yes then I want this string to be separated in **"Something" & "[Anything]"**.
Need some help with regEx for this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `String.split("[");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String test = "Something[Anything]";
    if (test.matches(".*\\[.*\\].*")) { // checks if in the string presents open and close square brackets
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\[.*?\\])");
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(test);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Something
[Anything]
```

---

Or, as suggested by @madatx, without first check:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\[.*?\\])");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(test);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Same output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex withour checking the square brackets.
This could work:

```
String strPattern = "(.+)(\\[.+\\])";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(strPattern);  
Matcher m = p.matcher("<yout string>"); 
if (m.matches()){
    <your code here>
}
```

Comment: A little note, your code will output **"Something"** & **"Anything"**, so you to change a little your second grouping to `"(.+)(\\[.+\\])"`.